# Implementing Upgrade Feature in iPhone App

Tags: ios

I already have an app in the app store which is a paid app. Now, I want to make the app free but put an option for *NEW* users to upgrade for the price. The old users can continue using all the new features of the app since they have already paid. My problem is that how will I track and distinguish new vs old users.

I think my answer is Receipt Validation in iOS 7 but it looks super complicated to implement. Any recommendations?

**UPDATE: WRONG SOLUTION! DON'T DO THIS**

One solution that has been floating around on the web is to save the version in NSUserDefaults. While that would work but what happens if the user deletes the app and reinstall it again. NSUserDefaults will be gone and then we are going to force the user to buy the app again or upgrade it again.

Comment: You are correct. This can only be done in iOS 7 through receipt validation and verifying which version of the app the user originally purchased.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question to include one other method which I do NOT believe is a good solution but have been advised on many different posts on StackOverFlow.

Comment: No, that solution doesn't work in many cases. Receipt validation in iOS 7 is the only valid way to properly convert a paid app to a free app without making at least some existing paid users pay again.

Comment: Yes! I agree and I also mentioned that the NSUserDefaults solution is WRONG. Thanks!